# No proper scrolling in webpage which uses `twitter-bootstrap`

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I wrote a webpage as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pv984vg2/). I added `overflow: auto` to body like this:

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
.containerA{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But the page isn't scrolling as shown in `jsfiddle`. How can I add scroll?

Comment: why would you have set height to 100% if you want it to scroll?

Comment: Well... I gave like this: `height: auto;`.... But no scroll

Comment: What part are you expecting to scroll?

Comment: The page will not scroll if there is not enough content to make it scroll.

Comment: There is already enough content.. do you see that blue `div` which comes between `imgTwo` and `nav`? Its `height` is 61%, more than enough

Comment: because. the blue div is positioned absolutely, so the containing div will not expand to contain it. position your blue div relative and give it a height of 500px, and you will see some scrolling.

Comment: Can you check this `jsfiddle`? http://jsfiddle.net/pv984vg2/4/... It isn't proper, footer should stay at bottom